# Order of Divs in html page

Tags: html, css

I've written this code for making 3 divs but the problem is I want the purple div (menu2 class) appear next to the green div (menu1) but this appears to the bottom. Thanks for your help.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.menu1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CCFF33;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.menu2 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF99FF;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="menu1">menu1<br />
  <p>lorem ipsum </p><br />
  <p> dolor sit amet</p><br />
  <p> eirmod tempor invidunt </p><br />
</div>
<div class="menu2">menu2</div>
```

Comment: You have different options, either `float:left` or `display:inline-block` or `flexbox` layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use Float**

Float was never meant for creating layouts. It changes the flow of order.

Use the modern web standard Example : Flexbox or Grid.

With flex box it is just one line of code.
For that first you have to put your menu1 and menu2 inside a parent div

Example :

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="menu-1"></div>
    <div className="menu-2"></div>
</div>
```

And then put `display : flex` to **container** class

Example :

```
.container{
    display:flex;
}
```

And there you have it , Nice and clean.

Comment: Was great tnx . :) yes flex is very better than float attribute.

Answer (score 1):

most simply you just add [`float:left;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) on both menues like:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.header
{

  height:10%;
  background-color:#FFCC00;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:24px;
}
.menu1
{
float:left; /* add this line */
width:30%;
height:100%;
background-color:#CCFF33;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}
.menu2
{
float:left;  /* add this line */
width:70%;
height:100%;
background-color:#FF99FF;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="menu1">menu1<br />
<p>lorem ipsum </p><br />
<p> dolor sit amet</p><br />
<p> eirmod tempor invidunt </p><br />
</div>
<div class="menu2">menu2</div>
```

Comment: one div with float left and other one float right. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One good way to do this would be to wrap both of those components into a flexbox. Flexboxes are great, because they get rid of empty space issues that you'll have with other methods like using `display: inline-block`.

Here's an example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu1">
  منو کناری <br />
  <p> soft98.ir </p><br />
  <p> softgozar.com </p><br />
  <p> bmi.ir </p><br />
  </div>
  <div class="menu2">منوی اصلی </div>
</div>
```

CSS for the container:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Was great ! :)))

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left` in menu1 amd menu2 classes

```
.menu1
{
width:30%;
height:100%;
background-color:#CCFF33;
text-align:center;
display:block;
float:left;
}
.menu2
{
width:70%;
height:100%;
background-color:#FF99FF;
text-align:center;
display:block;
float:left;
}
```